# Is the Jacobian matrix calculation process correctly on this energy function?

Tags: optimization, computer-vision

When I implemented the paper [Dynamic Fusion](https://rse-lab.cs.washington.edu/papers/dynamic-fusion-cvpr-2015.pdf) published in 2015 CVPR, I came into the trouble with how to solve the energy function:

$$E(W_t, V, D_t, \mathcal{E}) = \text{Data}(W_t, V, D_t) + λ\text{Reg}(W_t, \mathcal{E})$$

Where:

- `Wt` is a set of 4x4 transformation matrix at time `t`;
- `V` is a set of 3D vertices from canonical model;
- `Dt` is a depth map at time `t`;
- `ε` is used to find `Wt` matrices;
- `Data` is a point-to-plane error;
- `Reg` is a smooth term which enforce the two adjacent transformation matrix `W` to be similar.

To simplify the question, I try to solve the `Data` term and throw away `Reg` term.
$$E(W_t, V, D_t, \mathcal{E}) = \text{Data}(W_t, V, D_t)$$

Here is the `Data` term:

\begin{align*}
r &= \text{Data}(W_t, V, D_t)= \sum_u n_u^{\intercal}\cdot (v_u-vl) \\
where,\text{v}_u &= W_t×\text{v}(u)  \\
\text{n}_u &= W_t×\text{n}(u)  
\end{align*}

All the information but $W_t$ is known, use Gauss-Newton to solve the parameter:
$$\begin{gather*}
\underset{W_t}{\text{minimize}}\ r^2 \\
W_t^{(t+1)} = W_t^t - (J^\intercal J)^{-1}Jr
\end{gather*}$$

It seems to me that I need to calculate the Jacobian matrix $J$, so I expand `r` in matrix form:
$where\ W_t=$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & -\gamma & \beta & t_x \\
    \gamma & 1 & -\alpha & t_y \\
    -\beta & \alpha & 1 & t_z \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$v, n, vl$ are all 4x1 vector. (sorry, I don't know how to display matrix multiplication)

If I print all of the calculation, there are about 50 values containing $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,t_x,t_y,t_z)$ to sum up for one `Data` term. My question is, can I directly do partial differential to the parameters $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,t_x,t_y,t_z)$ of a $W_t$ matrix to get Jacobian matrix $J$?  It it correct to update $W_t$ by $W_t^{(t+1)} = W_t^t - (J^\intercal J)^{-1}Jr$?
I cannot believe this is a good approach because it is kind of messy, and maybe inefficient.
Please give me some advice how to solve this energy function, and I am curious why researchers only give energy function without explicit deviation on how to solve the function. Because energy function deviation is a common knowledge? If so, which course teach about it? I really want to take a course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an equation to be solved; it is an objective function to be minimized.  They apparently describe how they optimize it in Section 3.3.3 of the paper.  I suggest trying to understand that section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agree, one of the obstacles is to understand proper nouns mentioned in this sector, such as normal equation, pre-conditioned conjugate gradient descent solve, sparse Cholesky factorization, etc. Maybe I will know the solution after grasping these knowledge.